# Fetch form_params data from Guzzle post request in lumen api

Tags: laravel, lumen, guzzle

In my laravel 5.7 app, I have a controller with the following method that sends a post request using GuzzleHttp\Client to my lumen api.

```
public function insert(Request $request)
    { 
        $domain = Config::get('url.gcr_api'); // gcr_api is defined in app/config/url.php
        $url = $domain . "/api/v1/campaign/insert"; 

        $campaign_name =  $request->input('campaign_name');
        $campaign_provider =  $request->input('campaign_provider');

        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url , [
                                'headers' => [
                                    'X-XSRF-TOKEN' => csrf_token(),
                                ],
                                'form_params' => [
                                    'name' => $campaign_name, 
                                    'bank_id' => $campaign_provider,
                                ]
                            ]
                    );

        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        return $data;

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the lumen api that is called by the above method.

```
public function insert(Request $request) {
        try {
            $campaign_name =  $request->input('campaign_name');
            $campaign_provider =  $request->input('campaign_provider');

            $data = array('name' => $campaign_name, 'bank_id' => $campaign_provider);
            DB::table('campaign')->insert($data); 

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Campaign created successfully',
            );        
            return response()->json($response);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            // When query fails. 
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'failed',
                'message' => 'Failed to create campaign',
            );

            return response()->json($response);
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error everytime the insert method of my laravel app controller is called:

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ServerException (500) Server error: `POST
>   http://localhost:8000/api/v1/campaign/insert` resulted in a `500
>   Internal Server Error` response:

I think the error has something to do with my lumen api not able to fetch form_params data, so I commented out this block of code in my lumen api code and error disappears:

```
/*$campaign_name =  $request->input('campaign_name');
  $campaign_provider =  $request->input('campaign_provider');

  $data = array('name' => $campaign_name, 'bank_id' => $campaign_provider);
  DB::table('campaign')->insert($data); */
```

But I need to fetch the form_params data in my lumen api, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is partially correct, it can access the form_params, but the form_params you try to get differ from the actual parameters:

In order to pass the paramters you use the following array:

```
'form_params' => [
    'name' => $campaign_name, 
    'bank_id' => $campaign_provider,
]
```

This array will set the value to `$campaign_name` with the key 'name', and `$campaign_provider` to `bank_id`. Nothing wrong with this code so far.

However in your API you do the following:

```
$campaign_name =  $request->input('campaign_name');
$campaign_provider =  $request->input('campaign_provider');
```

However no key `campaign_name` or `campaign_provider` is present, since these have been changed to `name` and `bank_id`. So if you change this to the following it should work:

```
$campaign_name =  $request->input('name');
$campaign_provider =  $request->input('bank_id');
```

Comment: what the different using $client = new Client() , $response = $client->request() with using this->client->request() ?

Comment: $client is a local variable, not a class variable, so its not accessible from `$this`, first you have to instantiate it before you use it ;)

Comment: will it have the same result?

I'm always confused when I should write something have `this->`

Comment: No it will definitely not have the same result, which one you should use depends entirely on your class and function and if $client is a class variable which already has been instantiated (use `this`), or if you create the client in the function yourself (the client is not present as class variable, i.e. you can't use `this`), take a look at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/web-database-applications/0596005431/ch04.html or other Object oriented programming articles for more context on this ;)